# function computing and returning two values

Tags: c

I have a struct defined like this

```
struct statistics {
  double x;
  double y;
} statistics;
```

Ok, now another function fills an array of this struct declared

```
struct statistics* array_stats[DIMENSION]
```

My problem is that yet another function take all the array_stat structs as an input and computes two values that I have to use in a new struct

```
 struct statistics* result
```

I thought about writing a function like

```
void foo(struct statistics* output, struct statistics* input[]) {
  int i;
  for (i=0; i<DIMENSION; i++) {
    output->x += input[i]->x;
    output->y += input[i]->y;
  }
}
```

Outside the function I want being able to read output with `x` and `y` computed in the function (since I pass at the function the pointer to the struct I should be able to do so, am I wrong?
When I try to read result at the end I get garbage 
(the structures are properly malloc'ed and initialized to zeros, if I try to do the operations I need directly in the main I get good results.

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: This: `struct statistics* array_stats[DIMENSION]` is an array of *pointers* to the structure, not an array of structures.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that I can write a correct answer.

Answer (score -1):

There is no sense to declare the first parameter as a pointer to the structure. The function can be declared the following way

```
struct statistics foo( struct statistics * input[], size_t n ) 
{
    struct statistics output = { 0.0, 0.0 };

    size_t i = 0;    
    for ( ; i < n; i++ ) 
    {
        output.x += input[i]->x;
        output.y += input[i]->y;
    }

    return output;
}
```

and called like

```
struct statistics sum = foo( array_stats, DIMENSION );
```

As for your problem then it seems you pass a non-initialized pointer to the structure as the argument of the function.

Or maybe you allocate a structure within the function. However parameters of the function are its local variables. So the original argument will not be changed because the function deals with **a copy** of the original argument.

Answer (score -1):

> When I try to read result at the end I get garbage

Such comments are most often (perhaps even *always*) related to the consequences of *undefined behaviour*. Unfortunately, there is no undefined behaviour in the code you've provided. Your mistake is elsewhere, as you've realised in your first attempt to create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

> ... if I try to do the operations I need directly in the main I get good results.

If you want the best of our help, it might be wisest to persist in your efforts to create your MCVE. It takes persistence and time initially, however every skill improves with practice and soon enough you'll be whipping out MCVEs for complex problems like this in minutes, and realising answers to your own questions in the process.

Another alternative is to run a program called **valgrind**. It's a memory debugger, and it would tell you whether (and where) you're using uninitialised or clobbering data (among other problems), which would be my two guesses. Try to understand the messages valgrind is giving you by yourself, and if you don't understand those messages feel free to ask a question about them.